# How to save stock attribute value ('qty') for a product with Magento 2 objectmanager?

Tags: attributes, stock, save, object-manager

I've found out how to do this with other attributes.

For example a custom 'location' attribute:

```
    $product = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')- >load($post['id']);
    $productResource = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product');
    $product->setLocation('test');
    $productResource->saveAttribute($product, 'location');
```

This saves the 'location' attribute value for my product.

But how would you do this for the stock attribute 'qty'?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
)
{
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function yourMethod() {
    $sku = 'XYZ';
    $qty = 70;
    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty); // this line
    $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function __construct(
\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\StockRepositoryInterface
$productStockRepository
)
{
$this->productStockRepository = $productStockRepository;
}
$productStock = $productStockRegistry->getStockItem($entity->getId());

```
$productStock = $productStockRepository->get($entity->getId());

$productStock->setIsInStock(true);

$productStock->setQty(10);
```

$productStock->save();

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following code to save the stock value.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load();
$qty = 10;
$product->setStockData(
[
    'manage_stock' => '1',
    'is_in_stock' => '1',
    'qty' => $qty
]
```

);

Thanks.